# Printing vector elements with algorithm and/or functional library

Tags: c++

I was wondering if there is any way to print elements of vector only with using algorithm and/or functional library.
I've done it with std::for_each() but I still need to use lambda function (and with my own named function), is there any way to avoid it?
Here is my line of code that I need to replace with that new version:

```
std::for_each(v.begin(),v.end(), [](int n) { std::cout<<n<<std::endl;});
```

Thank You.

Comment: There is no built-in, ready to order function in the C++ library that prints the contents of the vector, or any container, all by itself. What you showed here is the closest match to it.

Comment: also note that "endl" flushes the stream after each element, generally not what you want

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This version doesn't need a lambda:

```
std::copy(v.begin(), v.end(),
          std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, "\n"));
```